pytorch for CUDA 11.8 version is not working when CUDA is actually 12.0 Windows
My computer has NVIDIA GPU (CUDA version 12.0)
I want to use pytorch for cuda, but can only find few Compute Platforms in PyTorch oficial website.
Therefore, I installed pytorch for CUDA 11.8 to a newly created conda environment:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia
Because the NVIDIA drivers are backward compatible as discussed here, I was expecting it to run smoothly.
But when I use it in VSCode, it complains with the below runtime error:
nvrtc: error: failed to open nvrtc-builtins64_118.dll.
  Make sure that nvrtc-builtins64_118.dll is installed correctly.

I can see the corresponding nvrtc-builtins64_118.dll is in the /bin of my conda environment.
How to fix this issue?
I tried uninstalling and installing pytorch and restarting the system
